# Changing favicon using favicon.ico

Tags: html, favicon

I had originally inserted a favicon to my html page but I'm trying to change it to put a different one but the first one seems stuck..It can't move, even when I remove the whole link tag for the favicon. I had generated a favicon (favicon.ico) and I'm using  but it's not working.

Comment: Clear caches in your browser? Or another scenario could be: The side runs on a server and you're testing it locally and you didn't change the path in the `<base>`-tag.

Comment: It worked. CLeared browser cache, but saw effect 2 days later.

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to caches, try clearing cache and also replacing favicon.ico file in your webroot. Browsers search for favicon.ico file in your webroot.

Comment: cleared browser cache. saw the effect 2days later though. thanx

Answer (score 0):

I've also experienced favicons the get cached aggressively by most browsers.
Creating a bookmark (delete old one first, if already bookmarked) for the page, seems to help sometimes.